# Thingsboard AWS server freezes

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, thingsboard

I want to run a self managed Thingsboard on AWS (t2.micro).

I have installed Thingsboard CE on a t2.micro AWS instance running Ubuntu 20.04 sever.
I followed the [aws setup](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/cluster/aws-self-hosted-setup/) and [Ubuntu install](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/ubuntu/?ubuntuThingsboardQueue=inmemory&ubuntuThingsboardDatabase=postgresql) guides(postgresql + built in queue service).

I also set up haproxy using [this](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/pe/add-haproxy-ubuntu/) guide.

I was able to successfully log in to my Thingsboard. I only changed the passwords and checked the basic functionalities, but didn't create any new dashboards or made any modifications.

After this I left the computer on, running Thingsboard. Next day I could not reach Thingsboard and although the AWS instance was running I could not ssh into it anymore. After stopping and starting(reboot didn't work) the instance everything was ok (could ssh and Thingsboard was reachable).

I can reproduce this failure just by leaving the instance on, it seems that after serveral hours (5-8 hrs) Thingsboard(or something else not sure) fails which freezes the whole computer.

I have checked two things:

1. I checked CPU utiization on AWS monitoring.
   It seems that after some hours there is a big jump in CPU load and then it drops back to almost zero. While Thingsboard is running, it is constant.[See printscreen from AWS monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wna3y.png)
2. I checked the Thingsboard logs (in /var/log/thingsboard):
   There are some errors, but unfortunately most of the things are not enough for me guess what could be a problem with the fresh installation. Here are some lines from the log:

> ```
> 2021-11-12 00:21:59,626 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-13] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Error parsing HTTP request header
>      Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
>     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name
> ```
>
> [0x160x030x010x00{0x010x000x00w0x030x030x170xb80xb80xe50xef0x000xb50x0a&0x930x020x00:0xde0xd70xa00xab0xb
> 70x8bU0xc00x92r0x9330x10O0x8c<o0xf70xf90x000x000x1a0xc0/0xc0+0xc00x110xc00x070xc00x130xc00x090xc00x140xc00x0a0x000x050x00/0x0050xc00x120x000x0a0x010x000x0040x000x050x000x050x010x000
> x000x000x000x000x0a0x000x080x000x060x000x170x000x180x000x190x000x0b0x000x020x010x000x000x0d0x000x100x000x0e0x040x010x040x030x020x010x020x030x040x010x050x010x060x010xff0x010x000x010x00...].
>
> ```
>   HTTP method names must be tokens
>             at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:417)
>             at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
>             at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
>             at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
>             at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
>             at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>             at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>             at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>             at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>             at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> 2021-11-12 00:22:01,486 [sql-queue-2-ts-4-thread-1] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate
> ```
>
> connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@4393afd0 (This connection
> has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime
> value.
> 2021-11-12 00:22:01,487 [sql-queue-2-ts latest-8-thread-1] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate
> connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@75b9496b (This connection
> has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime
> value.
> 2021-11-12 00:22:01,487 [sql-queue-0-ts latest-6-thread-1] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate
> connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@31849eec (This connection
> has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime
> value.
> 2021-11-12 00:22:01,487 [sql-queue-0-ts-2-thread-1] WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate
> connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@725fafe3 (This connection
> has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime
> value.

Some more:

```
2021-11-12 00:23:46,205 [sql-log-1-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - Queue-2 [TS Latest] queueSize [9] totalAdded [0] totalSaved [0] totalFailed [0]
2021-11-12 00:23:47,741 [sql-queue-0-ts-2-thread-1] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
2021-11-12 00:23:47,742 [sql-queue-2-ts-4-thread-1] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
2021-11-12 00:23:47,742 [sql-queue-2-ts latest-8-thread-1] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
2021-11-12 00:23:47,742 [sql-queue-0-ts latest-6-thread-1] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
2021-11-12 00:23:48,022 [sql-queue-0-ts-2-thread-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 634223ms.
2021-11-12 00:23:48,058 [sql-queue-0-ts-2-thread-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - This connection has been closed.
2021-11-12 00:23:48,022 [sql-queue-0-ts latest-6-thread-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 634223ms.
2021-11-12 00:23:48,059 [sql-queue-0-ts latest-6-thread-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - This connection has been closed.
2021-11-12 00:23:48,022 [sql-queue-2-ts latest-8-thread-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 624177ms.
2021-11-12 00:23:48,059 [sql-queue-2-ts latest-8-thread-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - This connection has been closed.
2021-11-12 00:23:48,023 [sql-queue-2-ts-4-thread-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 627819ms.
2021-11-12 00:23:48,059 [sql-queue-2-ts-4-thread-1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - This connection has been closed.
```

At the last:

```
2021-11-12 00:33:10,919 [sql-queue-0-ts latest-6-thread-1] ERROR o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - [TS Latest] Failed to save 1 entities
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:448)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:574)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:361)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
        at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sqlts.insert.latest.psql.PsqlLatestInsertTsRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$381b448c.saveOrUpdate(<generated>)
        at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sqlts.SqlTimeseriesLatestDao.lambda$init$3(SqlTimeseriesLatestDao.java:133)
        at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue.lambda$init$2(TbSqlBlockingQueue.java:71)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:138)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:276)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:284)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:184)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:402)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 634223ms.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:695)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:197)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:877)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.setNetworkTimeout(PgConnection.java:1610)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setNetworkTimeout(PoolBase.java:560)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:173)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186)
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

What is interesting that the timestaps on the CPU load going to max don't precisely correlate with the error messages in the log.
I apologise for the long error messages, but right now I don't know what could be the root cause.

I haven't tried to reinstall the whole computer yet.

My question would be, how should I proceed? Does anyone have ever faced similar issues? What logs/services/etc. should I check to grasp the root cause?

Should I try using a machine with more resources? Should I try other database and queue service?

In the current form this Thingsboard instance is not stable even for tests.

Edit: Sorry I could not format properly the first part of the error code.
Edit2: First link was wrong.

Comment: Maybe someone has hacked in and is mining crypto on your machine.  What ports does your SG open to the internet?

Comment: I opened all recommended ports for Thingsboard. TCP 22,80,443,1883 and UDP 5683 and 8080 so I can reach the TB Web UI. And what do you recommend to make sure whether someone has hacked into my computer and this is the root cause? Later on I plan to use VPN, but then I will try to implement it asap.

Comment: Are you ssh keys anywhere on the internet? I'm talking github repos, comapany sharepoint, teams files, sent as an email attachment to someone? I have also had issues with thingsboard freezing but those error logs are different to anything I've ever seen. Other things to check, is this a fresh install or do you have devices posting data into the platform. What DB are you using. What size volume is attached to your instance.

Comment: @JacksonB The ssh key is not on the internet afaik, but I am gonna change it. It is a totally fresh install I haven't started to send anything to TB. I have 1GB RAM (I have added the setting explained in the user guide for machines with less then 1GB RAM) and 16GB disk space.

Comment: @Glanthor if the problem persists I suggest making a bug report on the thingsboard github issues forum here: https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I **increased the RAM to 4GB** (from 1GB) the ThingsBoard server is up without problem. There are no sporadic freezes anyomore. As there were no other provable suggestions for the problem and now my system works without a problem I consider the question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points:

1. It looks like the operating system run out of memory and become unresponsive. To fix the issue try to [manage Java heap memory](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/ubuntu/#step-5-optional-memory-update-for-slow-machines-1gb-of-ram)
   For 4Gb instance, this Java heap limit JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M" may be useful, because Java uses some non-heap memory as well, PostgreSQL and others require some memory to run.
2. t2 instances on AWS may slow down the whole thing by CPU throttling. Instances like c6 or m5 are better options by performance.
3. In-memory queues may result in out-of-memory issues and data loss in case of a heavy message rate or some processing congestion due to the third party. Consider using [Kafka](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/docker/?ubuntuThingsboardQueue=kafka) to make your installation much stable and solid.